# Airline broke my bag but require a receipt to compensate from authorized company

Tags: luggage, new-york-city, turkish-airlines, damaged-luggage

I flew from Istanbul to JFK with Turkish airline a week ago and my bag came out missing a handle. I quickly went to the counter to claim the damage. The airline gave me an email for me to send all the documents; passport, ticket and the picture of damaged luggage. I sent them everything I got.

They sent another email asking for a receipt for the repair or if it cannot be repair it has to be a written note from authorized company stating that the bag cannot be repaired. I'm in New York. I just want to know if anyone has been into this situation and went to the authorized company to get the bag repaired?

Comment: Is it a branded bag?

Comment: No it's just normal bag.

Comment: I had a bag come out broken after a flight (a long cut through the side, right next to the handle.  I spoke with the airline baggage handler straight away - they took pictures of the damage on the spot and said that I would be contacted by the repair company.  About a week later I got a call from the repair company who said that they couldn't repair this damage, so they sent me a new (comparable) bag.  This was Virgin Atlantic flying from London to Boston.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Aleks I guess Turkish airline doesn't have that policy which is a shame.

Comment: @toy have you got any refund? They broke my bag wheel too :(

Comment: @Lafada I got the refund. It took me almost two months but I got the money.

Comment: And it's definitely worth it. It's mostly just waiting for their respond.

Comment: thanks toy, I got response, but they are asking for invoice for repaire, I am not planing to do that now, will do later, in this case, what should I have to do ? I wrote them, they can pick my bag and repaire, I dont have any problem. Will check what they will reply.

Comment: If you're not planning to do it right away, I think you should check with them if they are ok with that. They might have the timeframe for the case. But if they're willing to repair that for you then I think it's great. I hope it resolves soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reply is actually on the site of the TURKISH AIRLINES:

Damage or Loss

If damage to the baggage is of a kind that can be immediately ascertained (such as broken wheels or handles, tears or missing contents) the passenger must, on the same day and before leaving the arrival hall, applying to Station Lost and Found Offices with their

```
Travel ticket,
Baggage tag,
Identity document, and
Repair Invoice (if damaged),
Photograph (if damaged),
Purchase Invoice (if available),
```

where a damaged and/or lost baggage report will be prepared. If the damage is not of a kind that can be immediately ascertained, application must be made in person or in writing to the carrier within seven days of the date of travel.

Funny part: How can you have these in the same time:

1. on the same day
2. before leaving the arrival hall
3. Repair Invoice (if damaged)

You can't, because you would have to be able to repair the bag on the same day without leaving the arrival hall and receive the invoice for the repair. :) Basically this is a way of saying "you're on your own". Perfect legal defense, since I don't think there's a bag repair service on the arriving hall there :) :)

Alban

Answer (score 1):

I answer in case it can help someone else looking for this.

I'm right now in the same situation and a nice woman on the helpline explained me that I have to go to the shop where I bought the bag for repairing or getting this written note. So an "authorized compagny" might just be this shop.

This works only if you are near to the shop, which is fortunately often the case.